# Navigation page not showing back arrow in Prism.Forms Unity Application?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using the Prism.Forms.Unity

On drawer menu item selected user is navigating from MasterDetails page to next page, On the navigated page is not showing me that back arrow which will go back to my master details page.

I have tried using few options which are shown below

1. The first option I tried using the NavigationPage, starting the new page using prism navigation method

> _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/Add");

2. The second option I tried to set the property in XAML

> ```
> NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
> ```

[image]
These two ways are not working for me.
What is the correct way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no back button if you only have one page on the NavigationPage's navigation stack.  You need to have more than one page on the nav stack to have a back button. Otherwise, there is nothing to go back to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any alternative way to add it or we need to a custom button?

Comment: You only have one page on the stack.  There is nothing to go back to, so why add a back button

Comment: I am coming from master details page to next page, in my back stack master details page is available

Comment: If you are coming from a MDP, then you are navigating modally to a NavigationPage with a single page on its stack, which would still result in no back button.  If you are not coming from a MasterDetail, but instead updating the Detail of the MasterDetailPage, then you stil only have one page on the navigationPage's stack and hence no back button.